# node red switch node not working to switch images

Tags: node-red

my flow get data from a json file. Then the function node will return a number that is corresponding to the img in switch node. For example, if the icon is rain, than return msg.payload =1 , then in the switch node if msg.payload =1 then should switch it to the rain icon. But instead what i get is all of the icon come out at once. My function node is working as I check the debug node, it is returning the correct value.

[image: Screenshot of the flow]

[image: Screen shot of the Switching node]
[image: Screen shot of the template (rain)]
[image: Screen shot of the template (sun)]
[image: enter image description here(cloud)]
[image: dashboard config]
**Function node**

```
if (msg.payload.current_observation.icon === "rain") {
  var  test = 1 ;
msg.payload = test;
return msg;
} 

else if (msg.payload.current_observation.icon === "clear") {
  var  test = 2 ;
msg.payload = test;
return msg;
} 

else if (msg.payload.current_observation.icon === "cloudy") {
  var  test = 3 ;
msg.payload = test;
return msg;
}
```

Comment: Your bottom test is for a string not a number and all the nodes in the screen shot have undeployed changes

Comment: @hardillb  I change the bottom one to number. I have deployed them agian but still three img display at the same time.

Comment: The switch node should work as expected (as demonstrated here https://pastebin.com/JYRBBKKZ). What happens if you connect 3 debug nodes to outputs of the switch?

Comment: @hardillb only one of them return their number which is same as the function debug.

Comment: yes, but it proves that the switch is not the problem here. Edit the question to include the content of the 3 template nodes and the details of the dashboard config, so we can see what you are trying to get them to do. I suspect you only want 1 template node that switches what it displays not 3

Comment: @hardillb i had edited the question and include 3 template nodes details and dashboard config on it. Yes, i only want 1 template node display at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a single template node with something like this:

```
<div ng-if="msg.payload === 1">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ycv4ZSv.png">
</div>
<div ng-if="msg.payload === 2">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0IOLemr.png">
</div>
<div ng-if="msg.payload === 3">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CcTjBES.png">
</div>
```

You can remove the switch node and link the function node directly to the template node.

Comment: that's work thanks. if I want to use different image during the day and during the night, can I use a switch node? or is it still have to be done within the template node?

Comment: Use the same template node, just add another field to the `msg` object to indicate day/night and add the required tests to the `ng-if` sections

Comment: so if I want to have two statement in ng-if section, shoud it be something like this? `<div ng-if="msg.payload ===2 && msg.time === 1">`?